# Struts 2 Framework - Redirect to Action

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

Good day!

I am currently studying Struts 2 and I am quite confused with the xml. I don't know where to start.

I want my index.jsp to go to my Display Action Class So My codes is as follows:

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
   <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=package.action/DisplayContactAction">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
   <action name="index">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">HelloWorld</param>
            <param name="namespace">/example</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Can anyone explain to me what the code on the struts.xml above means.

After I redirect my page to the action class, i want it to go to the display.jsp

Action Class

```
    private ArrayList<Contacts> contactsList;
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String telNumber;
    private String email;

    public String execute() {
        String result = null;

        ContactsManager contactsManager = ContactsManager.getInstance();
        contactsList = ContactsManager.getContactsList();

        result = "success";
        return result;
     }
```

Now... How can I pass the value using xml?
Also, how can i transfer the data generated on my action class to the jsp?

Thank you.

Comment: You should first try to understand the basic struts2 worflow, with the default type (dispatch), (typically one action to execute the logic of the request, and one jsp to show the results). Only when you get this clear, try to understand the particular (much less used) `redirectAction` type, which results in the invocation of another action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me what the code on the struts.xml above means.

The following result would redirect to the URL for the HelloWorld action (likely /example/HelloWorld).

```
<result type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">HelloWorld</param>
    <param name="namespace">/example</param>
</result>
```

It calls the `getUriFromActionMapping(ActionMapping)` method of the `ActionMapper` to determine the URL to redirect to. You could also use a standard redirect type (`type="redirect"`).

> Also, how can i transfer the data generated on my action class to the jsp?

You'll need a getter to expose the data and then you can access it in the JSP.